# ARKIT - How to convert a position (GPS coordinates) relative to the real world origin to be relative to scenekit rootnode instead

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

So I'll try to explain my problem here. Im trying to place a node in scenekit from real world coordinates (GPS). I've tried to convert the wgs 84 coordinates to 3D cartesian, but that would make the coordinates relative to the ecef world origin. I would like to have the coordinates relative to the rootnode of the sceneview instead and I have no clue how to accomplish this.

I have no knowledge in matrix conversion nor math. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or provide a solution, written in any programming language. Thank you in advance

This is the formula used for translating gps coordinates to ecef, written in swift 4

```
    static func wgsllh2ecef(llh: [Double]) -> [Double]{
        let d: Double = WGS84_E * sin(llh[0])
        let N: Double = WGS84_A / sqrt(1 - d * d)

        let x = (N + llh[2]) * cos(llh[0]) * cos(llh[1])
        let y = (N + llh[2]) * cos(llh[0]) * sin(llh[1])
        let z = ((1 - WGS84_E * WGS84_E) * N + llh[2]) * sin(llh[0])
        return [x,y,z]
    }
```